# JavaScript - Object creating with reduce method and ({}) meaning

Tags: javascript, object, frontend, reduce

I have been learning JS for few months now, and everything is going good, but sometimes I encounter things I do not understand or I did miss them.
So, I was doing some Object oriented exercises and my assignment was to convert some values into numbers.
I wasn't sure how to do it, and after some researching I came up with this function:

```
function convertToNumber(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: +v }), {});
}
```

Things I do not understand are:

1. Why do we need to use`({ })` and not only`{}`? I guess it have something to do with object concatenation, but would like to be sure.
2. Why do I need to put key in`[ ]` brackets? Is it because at first I used spread operator on object? Is it like writing `acc[k]` in some sense?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**- Why do we need to use `({ })` and not only `{}`? I guess it has something to do with object concatenation but would like to be sure.**

This is used to directly return an object in the arrow function to distinguish it from the parenthesis used to wrap the function body. The two are the same:

```
(acc, [k, v]) => ({ ...acc, [k]: +v })
```

```
(acc, [k, v]) => { return { ...acc, [k]: +v }; }
```

**- Why do I need to put the key in `[ ]` brackets? Is it because at first, I used the spread operator on the object? Is it like writing `acc[k]` in some sense?**

The brackets are mainly used to set the key as the dynamic value of `k`. Here is a simple example:

```js
const x = 'id';
console.log({ x: 1 });
console.log({ [x]: 1 });
```